# In UUPS proxy pattern how does logic contract updates the storage in proxy?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I tried to find the answer but cannot and cannot wrap my head around this, so any help is appreciated.

So UUPS proxies store the upgrade logic inside the logic contract and the implementation address is stored in keccak256("PROXIABLE") so its random and unique,

My question is how is the upgrade performed? is it performed through the proxy delegating the call to logic contract? if so it makes sense, if not is the implementation updated through logic contract? in that case how does the logic contract tells the proxy contract about the update.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes indeed, the update logic is within the logic contact (implementation), however as the execution happens in the context of the proxy with `delegatecall()`, when the logic contract updates the implementation address, will be stored in the proxy contract state and the next delegate call will use the new logic (implementation) address.

Hope it helps